# How do I update all the columns named 'ModifiedBy' in all tables of a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove all personal data from a database. Many of the tables have a 'ModifiedBy' column which contains users' emails.

Is there a convenient way to iterate over every table in the database which has a ModifiedBy column and run an update such as the one below:

```
UPDATE [TableName] 
SET [ModifiedBy] = CONVERT (
   nvarchar(max), 
   HASHBYTES('SHA', CONCAT('MY_SALT_VALUE', [ModifiedBy])), 
   2
)
```

Comment: Does the Users table have a unique INT primary key? If so, you'd be better off creating a new temp ModifiedBy column of type INT, updating that using the email in the original column as the lookup, dropping the old ModifiedBy columns, and then only hashing the email address in the Users table.

Comment: @HardCode ints based upon there userid aren't anonymous enough for GDPR - that still PII.

Comment: @Zoe - why remove my working code?  It wasn't the same as Zhorov's.  Anybody who gets errors using Zhorov's answer check the edit history of this question to see what worked on my machine.

Comment: @RAM answers don't go in the question. Either post a comment on the answer, [or post your own answer](stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dynamic statement based on `sys.columns`, `sys.tables` and `sys.schemas` system views is a possible option. Note, that the [return type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types) of `STRING_AGG()` depends on the first argument (expression), so you need an additional cast\convert to avoid truncation:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @err int

SELECT @stm = STRING_AGG(
   CAST(CONCAT(
      N'UPDATE ',
      QUOTENAME(sch.[name]), N'.', QUOTENAME(tab.[name]),
      N' SET ', 
      QUOTENAME(col.[name]), N' = CONVERT (nvarchar(max), HASHBYTES(''SHA'', CONCAT(''MY_SALT_VALUE'', ',
      QUOTENAME(col.[name]), N')), 2)'
   ) AS nvarchar(max)),
   '; '
)
FROM sys.columns col
JOIN sys.tables tab ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id
WHERE col.[name] = 'ModifiedBy' 

PRINT @stm
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
IF @err <> 0 PRINT 'Error found'
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made a couple of changes to get around a problem I had with STRING_AGG (STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.) and it worked.
I'm updating my question with the final slution which worked for me.

Comment: @RAM, the [return type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types) of `STRING_AGG()` depends on first argument (expression), so you need an additional cast\convert.

Comment: @Charlieface, good point, the return type of `STRING_AGG` depends on the data type of the first argument.